# How many quartermasters are there in the slums?

Tags: dying-light

I see the main quartermaster in the Tower, and Spike in the safe house just south, are there any more in the slums?  I'm at level 10 if that matters.

Comment: Those are the only ones, but Spike is not permanent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the fact that you do not have the DLC ["The Following"](http://dyinglight.wikia.com/wiki/The_Following). Then Yes there are only two Which are [located](http://dyinglight.wikia.com/wiki/Quartermaster) :

> The Slums: Spike is a quartermaster initially located not far from The
> Tower, within the safe zone around Dr. Zere's trailer.
>
> OldTown: When Kyle is in Old Town Spike can be found in the
> 'primary' safe zone of the area towards the north west of the city.
> Enter the safe zone and head to the back of the building.

If you do have the DLC then there is a third, located here:

> The Countryside: When Kyle is in Old Town Spike can be found in the
> 'primary' safe zone of the area towards the north west of the city.
> Enter the safe zone and head to the back of the building.

Comment: Thanks.  You forgot the primary quartermaster in the Tower.